# "Open folder" action, doesn't work in Nautilus

Tags: 15.04, nautilus, dolphin

A time ago, I tried to set dolphin by default file manager in my Ubuntu 15.04
I'm not a expert user, I just follow the tutorials in the web, and I changed a lot of keys in folders like: user, bit, etc...
The final result, it doesn't work...and finally my Nautilus file manager now doesn't work properly. 
For example, using software like Transmission-torrent, I click in "open folder" (right rick option) and ..nothing

I don't want to reinstall all my system for this little detail...so I will very appreciate your help. (sorry for my bad English, I'm spanish speaker)

:D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what went wrong with your nautilus but if you really think you kinda messed up with your file manager, you can try uninstalling your nautilus completely and reinstall. To do so, follow this

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus
```

This will uninstall your nautilus and remove it's configuration files as well

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This will remove all it's dependencies that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for the package and are now no longer needed.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Just in case your linux is configured to cache the retrieved package

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

This will install nautilus from Ubuntu repo again